# Add a space or tab before the last character in each line

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a file with a list of values that end with a letter. Is there an easy way to add a space or tab before the last character of each line to separate the number from the letter?

```
44A  
354T  
1453C  
77D
```

So that the output looks like this:

```
44 A  
354 T  
1453 C  
77 D
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you never have any white space after the last character and before the end of the line, use:

```
sed 's/.$/ &/' file
```

or

```
perl -pe 's/.$/ $&/' file
```

If you can have whitespace before the end of the line, use this instead:

```
perl -pe 's/(.*)(\S)/$1 $2/' file
```

Comment: Nice. Also `s/(?=\S\s+$)/ /` but I don't think that gains anything over your sol'n

Answer (score 4):

This works for the stated case:

```
sed 's/\(.\)$/\ \1/' file.txt
```

It will break down if you want a space anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

if lines are not empty...

```
perl -pe 'substr($_,-2,0)=" "'
```

Answer (score 0):

In vi, you can do it with:

```
:%s/\(.\)$/ \1/
```

Broken down, this is:

```
:%s    #Apply substitution to all lines
   /\(.\)$    #Search for a single character followed by the end of the line
          / \1/    #Replace with a space followed by that character
```

This does assume you don't have any whitespace at the end of your lines.  If that's not always the case, use:

```
:%s/\(\S\)\s*$/ \1/
```

This will strip off any trailing whitespace and add a single space before the last remaining character on each line.